# How can entity be persisted twice?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a weird problem : Two of my entities get persisted twice randomly.
Let me explain : 
I have an Entity Project, that has a ManyToOne relation to Transaction. A project also has a ManyToOne relationship to a customer. 
This is the code that cause the issue :

```
        $transaction = new TransactionBuyer();

        if ($fees) {
            $option = new TransactionOptions();
            //setters 
            $em->persist($option);
        }

        $warrantyOption = new TransactionOptions();
        //other setters
        $deposit = new Deposit();
        // setters

        $transaction->setCustomer($customer);
        $transaction->setAd($ad);
        $transaction->setDeliveryMode($deliveryMode);
        $transaction->setDeposit($deposit);

        $ad->setStatus(AdStatus::AD_PENDING_SELL);
        $project = new CustomerProjectBuy();
        $project->setCustomer($customer);
        $project->setTransactionBuyer($transaction);
        $project->setTransactionSeller($transactionSeller);
        $project->setPromoCode($promoCode);
        $ad->getCar()->addCustomerProject($project);


        $transactionSeller->addProject($project);
        foreach ($transactionSeller->getProjects() as $project) {
            if ($project instanceof CustomerProjectSell) {
                $project->setTransactionBuyer($transaction);
            }
        }
        $customer->addProject($project);
        $transaction->addProject($project);
        $customer->setTermsOfSaleAccepted(true);

        $projectSell = $em->getRepository('CoreBundle:CustomerProjectSell')->findOneBy(['car' => $ad->getCar(), 'transactionSeller' => $transactionSeller]);
        $projectSell->setTransactionBuyer($transaction);

        $em->persist($deposit);
        $em->persist($transaction);
        $em->persist($warrantyOption);
        $em->persist($project);
        $em->flush();
```

The transaction and project got persisted twice some times (like one time out of 3). The two entities contains the same data.
I cannot reproduce the issue on my local environnement.
And recently I got this problem in production :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE Ad SET `Status` = ?, LastUpdateDate = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [5, "2019-02-04 12:01:10", 6098]:

SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

This exception is at the moment of the flush. Can it be linked ?

Comment: Looks to me like the whole code you showed is executed multiple times. Can you detect any redirects when you get duplicate transactions?

Comment: I watched the Apache access logs and I saw only one call to this url.

Comment: if fees is true then TransactionOptions() will always be persisted twice.

Comment: @NabilAfraz It is normal, this entity should be created twice.

Comment: I think what could be part of the problem is that you fetch an existing project `$projectSell` which reuses the `$transaction` from the new project `$project` You might want to move this fetch and setting the transaction to after flush and then flush again. Maybe that will help

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with the data in the DB? For example floating records? Doctrine Entity persistence is done by the UnitOfWork and that uses unique object hash references to update objects uniquely. To check, run an `spl_object_hash($entity)` on all of your objects which you've touched, specifically those you suspect of being an issue, and compare their hashes. Could it be your setting a reference to your `$ad` object and later set it to be referenced elsewhere, but the two "from" locations are incompatible? Anyway food for thought ;-)

Comment: I don't know if it will work but can you move this line `$ad->getCar()->addCustomerProject($project);` after `$project` is persisted and try again ?

Comment: Any `cascade` options in your entities?

Comment: @StephanVierkant Yes, persist on every relations, and on some I got a remove.

Comment: If you have set `cascade persist` on the project field in your Transaction entity and on the Transaction field in your Project entity; when you persist the transaction object, the related project gets persist also. So is it when you persist the project.

Comment: @titili Ah yes, may be this is it, but in this case, why I can't reproduce this in my dev environnement and it is not duplicated every time in production ? Like one time out of three ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov I'm not sure why it seems to happen randomly. But you have to think about the way you persist your entities and set the cascade operation. For instance, if a project is always associated to a transaction, maybe you should only persist a project throught a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Do not persist your children entity, Just set your children entities to it's parent entity and only persist your main entity.

If we consider project as main entity, you should only persist it as following.

`$em->persist($project);`

Read below article for step by step guideline.
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-doctrine-relations/save-relation#